# Instrumenting the execution of a Java application (not just the bytecode)

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am doing some Java application instrumentation. But the available instrumentation tools that use ASM or BCEL only allow to instrument the bytecode. Do you guys know of some tool that can instrument the execution of the application (as in the stuff that is not just there in bytecode but the JVM did it).

For example, if the application has a class A

```
class A
{
 int a;

 public A()
 {}
}
```

When I do `A obj = new A()`, then the byte code will not contain any write to `obj.a`, but the JVM will do that, **AFIK**.

There is other stuff as well that can not be captured in bytecode. So, can you guys tell me if there exists such a framework that can capture the operations executed by the JVM.

Comment: Most useful instrumentation can be achieved by adding byte code. What is it you are trying to do?  When the byte code is compiled to machine code and the program is following the expected path, the JIT isn't doing anything. So if you only monitored the JVM, you might finds its not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want complete control over the instrumentation, you ideally need complete access to the source and the ability to modify it.  Otherwise you are at the mercy of what the bytecode retains.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a program transformation system that provides such access to the source.  Using its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html), DMS can parse (Java) code, build ASTs, apply arbitrary transforms to the ASTs and regenerated instrumented Java code.

What you choose to instrument is up to you.  This [paper on instrumenting code](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf) describes how to build classic test coverage, but the ideas are general.

Comment: That wouldn't instrument internal JVM operations either, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The intenal JVM actions are mostly driven by the explicit actions implied by the Java semantics, so you can in effect determine them by instrumenting the source coded.  OP's interest in instrumenting calls on "new" can be done by instrumenting source (as well as instrumenting byte code).  The source code gives you access to all the variable names, etc. which the byte code may or may not have.  What you can't instrument from the source, or the byte code, are implicit JVM operations such as garbage collection or thread switching.

Comment: And implicit initialization, which is what they were asking about. It can be deduced, but not instrumented, without a jvm modification.